# JqGrid not displaying the data first time but works after that

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jqgrid

The attached piece of code runs when I pass parameters srchkey and srchvalue from a hidden field.
But while doing the same, JqGrid is not showing the data the first time although jqGrid getting data as we can see it in Developer Tool.
While second time onwards, it's loading the data  and showing it perfectly.
Please help us as  we are trapped in this issue for the last few days

Thanks in advance.

```js
 function BindGrid() {
            $("#divgraph").hide();
            debugger;
            $('#grid').jqGrid('GridUnload');
            var arr = $("#hdnSearch").val().split('|');
            var srchkey = arr[0];
            var srchval = arr[1];

            
            // dynamic columns in grid
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/GetGenericSearch',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { key: srchkey, value: srchval },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#ExportExcel").show();
                    var colM = JSON.parse(result.colModel);

                    var colN = JSON.parse(result.colNames);
                    if (srchkey.indexOf("PId") > 0 || srchkey.indexOf("PName") > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < colM.length; i++) {
                            if (colM[i].name.toString().indexOf("PROJECTID") > -1) {
                                colM[i].key = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (srchkey.indexOf("AId") > 0 || srchkey.indexOf("AName") > 0) {
                        var myMonthsTemplate = {
                            sorttype: 'float', search: true, searchtype: 'float', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge'] }, formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
                                var value = parseFloat(cellvalue), retult, op = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.float);
                                if (!$.fmatter.isUndefined(options.colModel.formatoptions)) {
                                    op = $.extend({}, op, options.colModel.formatoptions);
                                } retult = $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(Math.abs(value), op); return (value >= 0 ? retult : '(' + retult + ')');
                             }, cellattr: function (rowid, cellvalue) { return parseFloat(cellvalue) < 7 ? 'style="color:red ;"' : parseFloat(cellvalue) < 8 ? 'style="color:orange ;"' : 'style="color:green ;"' }
                        };
                        for (var i = 0; i < colM.length; i++) {
                            if ((typeof colM[i].template != "undefined")) {
                                colM[i].template = myMonthsTemplate;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    var colData = result.data;

                    
                    $("#grid").jqGrid({
                           datatype: 'json',
                         
                        mtype: 'GET',
                        url: '/Admin/GetGenericSearchData',
                        colNames: colN,
                        colModel: colM,

                        jsonReader: {
                            
                            root: "rows",
                            page: "page",
                            total: "total",
                            records: "records",
                            repeatitems: false,
                        },
                        postData: { key: srchkey, value: srchval },
                        gridview: true,
                        pager: '#pager',
                        height: "140px",
                        width: "1200px",
                        rowNum: 6,
                        rowList: [6, 12, 18, 24],
                        viewrecords: true,
                         loadonce: true,
                        autowidth: true,
                        shrinkToFit: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        
                         
                        loadComplete: function () {
     
                            $("#mygrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { key: srchkey, value: srchval } }).trigger('reloadGrid');;
                          


                            if (srchkey.indexOf("PId") > 0 || srchkey.indexOf("PName") > 0) {
                                var columnNames = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');
                                var columnModel = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                                var ids = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                                    for (var j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
                                        if (columnNames[j] == "GREEN") {
                                            // assign color to grid row
                                            //$("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[1], false, 'time_ingreen');

                                            jQuery('#grid').setCell(ids[i], columnModel[j].name, '', 'time_ingreen');
                                        }
                                        else if (columnNames[j] == "AMBER") {
                                            jQuery('#grid').setCell(ids[i], columnModel[j].name, '', 'time_inorange');
                                        }
                                        else if (columnNames[j] == "RED") {
                                            jQuery('#grid').setCell(ids[i], columnModel[j].name, '', 'time_inred');
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                           
                        },



                    })
                    .navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });


                    if (srchkey.indexOf("PId") > 0 || srchkey.indexOf("PName") > 0) {
                    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                        useColSpanStyle: true,
                        groupHeaders: [
                          { startColumnName: 'AMBERJanuary', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'January' },
                          { startColumnName: 'AMBERFebruary', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'February' },
                           { startColumnName: 'AMBERMarch', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'March' },
                          { startColumnName: 'AMBERApril', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'April' },
                           { startColumnName: 'AMBERMay', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'May' },
                           { startColumnName: 'AMBERJune', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'June' }
                    ]
                    });
                }



                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }); 
        }
```

```html
  <table id="grid"></table>
                             <div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JqGrid needs initialisation on document.ready function and for that I created a dummy grid with no data. and then the code is working fine.
Although its not a proper and recommended solution , but this works :)